# get facebook details after login with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, ionic-framework

I'm trying to implement the facebook login in my angular application. the login works alright but the issue is after the login i want to alert the data that is coming from facebook but I'm having problems with it.

```
.controller('facebook_login',['$scope', '$ionicModal', '$timeout', 'ngFB', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, ngFB) {
 $scope.fbLogin = function () {
    ngFB.login({scope: 'email,public_profile,publish_actions'}).then(
        function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                //alert('Facebook login succeeded, got access token: ' + response.authResponse.accessToken);
                //$scope.closeLogin();
                 ngFB.api({
                 path: '/me',
                 params: {fields: 'id,name'}
                 }).then(
                 function (user) {
            $scope.user = user;
            alert(params)
       });
            } else {
                alert('Facebook login failed');
            }
        });
};

}])
```

Comment: what problems do you have?

Comment: the alert doesn't even pop up

Answer (score 1):

Please try changing the params: fields to the following

```
fields: 'first_name,last_name,gender,email,picture'
```

Instead of invoking alert on the params, alert on the response object i.e. user in this case.

```
alert(user)
```

Comment: i get the return object, object

Comment: you should not use alert to debug, use console.log instead, with the chrome dev tools. you really need to learn how to debug js objects.

Comment: @luschn, i'm wondering if you could teach me how to put the values into a textbox after getting it from facebook